# split mysql regex into multiple lines

Tags: mysql, regex, multiline

I have a very long MySQL regex query that I would like to split into multiple lines but I haven't figured out how.
Short version:
    select * from table.ips where ipip not regexp '^4\.|^8\.|^12\.|^18\.' order by ipID;

Multi-line non-working version:

```
select * from table.ips where ipip not regexp '

^4\\.|

^8\\.|

^12\\.|

^18\\.

' order by ipID;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a free spacing mode in mysql regex...

How about using [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)?

```
select * from table.ips where ipip not regexp concat(
    '^4\\.|',
    '^8\\.|',
    '^12\\.|',
    '^18\\.'
)
```

Comment: will that make it less efficient?

Comment: It will add the necessary time to concatenate the strings, but that should be insignificant... The regex applied is the exact same.